# RUSLE model Equation using GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, rusle

[image]

```
var countries = ee.FeatureCollection("USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017");
var Madagascar = countries.filter(ee.Filter.eq('country_na', 'Madagascar'));
Map.addLayer(Madagascar, {}, "Madagascar");
Map.centerObject(Madagascar);

//I don't know how to turn my own R factor equation like this, kindly guide me please

var Precipitation_Mada = ee.Image("OpenLandMap/CLM/CLM_PRECIPITATION_SM2RAIN_M/v01");
var Annual_Precipitation_Mada = Precipitation_Mada.reduce(ee.Reducer.sum()).clip(Madagascar);
//use my formula on the picture bellow
var Monthly_Precipitation_Mada = ee.Image(10).pow(ee.Image(1.5).multiply(Precipitation_Mada.pow(2).divide(Annual_Precipitation_Mada).log10().subtract(-0.08188))).multiply(1.735)
var factorR = Monthly_Precipitation_Mada.reduce(ee.Reducer.sum()).clip(Madagascar);
Map.addLayer(factorR, imageVisParam,  'R factor Map', 0);

var Rfactor = factorR.visualize(imageVisParam);
```

Comment: If you don't know JS, better to download the images you want for your study area and then conduct soil loss modeling on your local machine.

Comment: Before you learn JS you also didn't know anything about it, so why you didn't give up and try something else?and then you want me to use local machine while I want to extend my knowledge, poor mindset

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need to put the source of all formulas displayed in above picture. It is necessary for corroborating the meaning of each variable used in the calculations.

On the other hand, it can be observed in above picture that you need a DEM map for calculating the slope (θ) used in S, β and m map calculations. For instance, S map can be calculated as follows:

```
var DEM = ee.Image("USGS/SRTMGL1_003").clip(Madagascar);
var elevation = DEM.select('elevation');
var slope = ee.Terrain.slope(elevation);

var S = img.where(slope.gte(0).and(slope.lt(5)), slope.divide(180).multiply(Math.PI).sin().multiply(10.8).add(0.03))
           .where(slope.gte(5).and(slope.lt(14)), slope.divide(180).multiply(Math.PI).sin().multiply(16.8).subtract(0.05))
           .where(slope.gte(14), slope.divide(180).multiply(Math.PI).sin().multiply(21.91).subtract(0.96))
           .rename('S');
```

Above code lines can be integrated in your code as follows for producing S, β and m maps:

```
var countries = ee.FeatureCollection("USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017");
var Madagascar = countries.filter(ee.Filter.eq('country_na', 'Madagascar'));
Map.addLayer(Madagascar, {}, "Madagascar");
Map.centerObject(Madagascar, 6);

//I don't know how to turn my own R factor equation like this, kindly guide me please

var Precipitation_Mada = ee.Image("OpenLandMap/CLM/CLM_PRECIPITATION_SM2RAIN_M/v01");
var Annual_Precipitation_Mada = Precipitation_Mada.reduce(ee.Reducer.sum()).clip(Madagascar);

var DEM = ee.Image("USGS/SRTMGL1_003");

//use my formula on the picture above
var Monthly_Precipitation_Mada = ee.Image(10).pow(ee.Image(1.5)
                                             .multiply(Precipitation_Mada.pow(2).divide(Annual_Precipitation_Mada)
                                             .log10()
                                             .subtract(-0.08188)))
                                             .multiply(1.735);

var factorR = Monthly_Precipitation_Mada.reduce(ee.Reducer.sum()).clip(Madagascar);

var DEM = ee.Image("USGS/SRTMGL1_003").clip(Madagascar);
var elevation = DEM.select('elevation');
var slope = ee.Terrain.slope(elevation);

//Map.addLayer(factorR, imageVisParam, 'R factor Map');

Map.addLayer(DEM, imageVisParam2, 'DEM', 0);

Map.addLayer(slope, imageVisParam3, 'slope', 0);

//var Rfactor = factorR.visualize(imageVisParam);

//producing S map

var img = ee.Image(-1).clip(Madagascar);

var S = img.where(slope.gte(0).and(slope.lt(5)), slope.divide(180).multiply(Math.PI).sin().multiply(10.8).add(0.03))
           .where(slope.gte(5).and(slope.lt(14)), slope.divide(180).multiply(Math.PI).sin().multiply(16.8).subtract(0.05))
           .where(slope.gte(14), slope.divide(180).multiply(Math.PI).sin().multiply(21.91).subtract(0.96))
           .rename('S');
  
Map.addLayer(S, {min: 0, 
                 max: 0.9, 
                 palette: ['blue','green','red']}, 
                 'S Map');


//producing beta map

var beta = slope.expression('sin((slope/180)*PI)/(3*sin((slope/180)*PI)**0.8 + 0.56)',
{
  'slope': slope.select('slope'),
  'PI': Math.PI
}).rename('beta');

Map.addLayer(beta, imageVisParam4, 'beta', 0);

//producing m map

var m = beta.expression('beta/(1 + beta)',
{
  'beta': beta.select('beta'),
}).rename('m');

Map.addLayer(m, imageVisParam5, 'm', 0);
```

After running complete [code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/053cf4a759c4952a877381614f54904c) in GEE code editor, result can be watched in following picture. S map is observed but β and m maps can also be displayed. The remaining variables cannot be calculated because the source of some of the above formulas is required..

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Sir, it is very helpful but I have one question for the R factor equation , I was using the Modified fournier formula so how you write it in the code?

Comment: Did you read the beggining of my answer? You need to put the source of all formulas displayed in above picture. It is necessary for corroborating the meaning of each variable used in the calculations. Reference to the Modified Fournier formula in your comment is not enough.

Comment: Yes please, I already added the R factor equation picture bellow in more details,  and my question is in the last formula down bellow, how to find the (a and b) parameters values?

Comment: okay,please check it out again

Answer (score 0):

With your edit you practically destroyed the purpose of this question related to RUSLE model equation. You deleted the other formulas for calculating the slope (θ) used in S, β and m map calculations.

Your new information corresponds to a new question related to determination of Modified Fournier Index (MFI) and its relation with RUSLE factor. However, it was impossible to relate it with RUSLE factor because the information was not included completely. By using GEE, MFI can be calculated as follows with 'OpenLandMap/CLM/CLM_PRECIPITATION_SM2RAIN_M/v01' product.

```
var bands = Precipitation_Mada.bandNames();

var list = bands.map(function(n) { 

  return Precipitation_Mada.select([n])
                           .rename('month') }
  
);

var collection = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(list);

print(collection);

var sum = collection.sum().rename('sum');

print(sum);

Map.addLayer(sum.select('sum'), imageVisParam6, 'sum precipitation', 0);

var cuad = collection.map(function (ele){
  
  return ee.Image(ele).multiply(ele);
  
});

print(cuad);

var sum_cuad = cuad.sum().rename('sum_cuad');

var MFI = sum_cuad.divide(sum);

var imageVisParam7 = {"opacity":1,
                      "bands":["sum_cuad"],
                      "min":48,
                      "max":319,
                      "palette":["ff2804","ff9a00","0affd3","0a32ff"]};

Map.addLayer(MFI, imageVisParam7, 'MFI');
```

Complete code can be found [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/e80583a346a3cb450049f8bdbb535478).

After running it, I got following result.

[image]

Comment: okay ,in this case is there any chance to get your email Sir so I can send your my proposal with all my RUSLE equation in it

Comment: this is my email please let's get in touch there : rogicarl14@gmail.com